# getting a query string param from an updated url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, server, single-page-application, query-string

I have a project I'm working on, on `VUE`, and at the final stage the project moves to a report, while the project is in the report mode I'm adding a query string with this specific mode that I want to identify on the server side, bur I cannot get the value.
When I get to the report mode, I try to get `window.location.search` and I get it without the parameter that I'm adding, I guess it happens because it is a single page application and it does not get it from the first time the project is loaded.
Is there a way to get this parameter?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Are you doing server side rendering or client side rending? With server side rendering, you don't have access to the window object on the initial load.